# squid3 auth thru samba using ntlm to AD doesn't work

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, samba, squid, ntlm

some users here are spending to much time exploring the WWW.
So big boss whats to get this under control.

We use a squid3 just for some security reason and chace benefits.
and now i'm trying to set up a new proxy on a different server (Debian 6)
Permissions are defined in AC and the squid3 should get the auth thru samba/winbind by using the ntlm protocol.

but i'll get all the time Access, denited.
it only works by using LDAP but thats not the way i need it.

here some log and confs

squid access.log

```
1326878095.784      1 192.168.15.27 TCP_DENIED/407 4049 GET http://at.msn.com/? -NONE/- text/html
1326878095.791      1 192.168.15.27 TCP_DENIED/407 4294 GET http://at.msn.com/? - NONE/- text/html
1326878095.803      9 192.168.15.27 TCP_DENIED/403 4028 GET http://at.msn.com/? kavan NONE/- text/html
1326878095.848      0 192.168.15.27 TCP_DENIED/403 3881 GET http://www.squid-cache.org/Artwork/SN.png kavan NONE/- text/html
1326878100.279      0 192.168.15.27 TCP_DENIED/403 3735 GET http://www.google.at/ kavan NONE/- text/html
1326878100.296      0 192.168.15.27 TCP_DENIED/403 3870 GET http://www.squid-cache.org/Artwork/SN.png kavan NONE/- text/html
1326878155.700      0 192.168.15.27 TCP_DENIED/407 4072 GET http://ie9cvlist.ie.microsoft.com/IE9CompatViewList.xml - NONE/- text/html
1326878155.705      2 192.168.15.27 TCP_DENIED/407 4317 GET http://ie9cvlist.ie.microsoft.com/IE9CompatViewList.xml - NONE/- text/html
1326878155.709      3 192.168.15.27 TCP_DENIED/403 4026 GET http://ie9cvlist.ie.microsoft.com/IE9CompatViewList.xml kavan NONE/- text/html
```

squid chace

```
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Creating Swap Directories
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Starting Squid Cache version 3.1.6 for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu...
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Process ID 17236
2012/01/18 10:12:49| With 65535 file descriptors available
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Initializing IP Cache...
2012/01/18 10:12:49| DNS Socket created at [::], FD 7
2012/01/18 10:12:49| DNS Socket created at 0.0.0.0, FD 8
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Adding nameserver 192.168.15.2 from /etc/resolv.conf
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Adding nameserver 192.168.15.19 from /etc/resolv.conf
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Adding nameserver 192.168.15.1 from /etc/resolv.conf
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Adding domain schoenbrunn.local from /etc/resolv.conf
2012/01/18 10:12:49| helperOpenServers: Starting 5/5 'squid_ldap_auth' processes
2012/01/18 10:12:49| helperOpenServers: Starting 10/10 'ntlm_auth' processes
2012/01/18 10:12:49| helperOpenServers: Starting 10/10 'squid_kerb_auth' processes
2012/01/18 10:12:49| squid_kerb_auth: INFO: Starting version 1.0.5
2012/01/18 10:12:49| squid_kerb_auth: INFO: Starting version 1.0.5
2012/01/18 10:12:49| squid_kerb_auth: INFO: Starting version 1.0.5
2012/01/18 10:12:49| squid_kerb_auth: INFO: Starting version 1.0.5
2012/01/18 10:12:49| squid_kerb_auth: INFO: Starting version 1.0.5
2012/01/18 10:12:49| squid_kerb_auth: INFO: Starting version 1.0.5
2012/01/18 10:12:49| squid_kerb_auth: INFO: Starting version 1.0.5
2012/01/18 10:12:49| squid_kerb_auth: INFO: Starting version 1.0.5
2012/01/18 10:12:49| helperOpenServers: Starting 5/5 'squid_ldap_group' processes
2012/01/18 10:12:49| squid_kerb_auth: INFO: Starting version 1.0.5
2012/01/18 10:12:49| squid_kerb_auth: INFO: Starting version 1.0.5
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Unlinkd pipe opened on FD 73
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Local cache digest enabled; rebuild/rewrite every 3600/3600 sec
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Store logging disabled
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Swap maxSize 0 + 262144 KB, estimated 20164 objects
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Target number of buckets: 1008
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Using 8192 Store buckets
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Max Mem  size: 262144 KB
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Max Swap size: 0 KB
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Using Least Load store dir selection
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Set Current Directory to /var/spool/squid3
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Loaded Icons.
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Accepting  HTTP connections at [::]:3128, FD 74.
2012/01/18 10:12:49| HTCP Disabled.
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Squid modules loaded: 0
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Adaptation support is off.
2012/01/18 10:12:49| Ready to serve requests.
2012/01/18 10:12:50| storeLateRelease: released 0 objects
```

smb.conf

```
# Domain Authntication Settings
        workgroup = <WORKGROUP>
        security = ads
        password server = <DOMAINNAME>.LOCAL
        realm = <DOMAINNAME>.LOCAL
        ldap ssl = no
# logging
        log level = 5
        max log size = 50
        # logs split per machine
        log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
        # max 50KB per log file, then rotate
;       max log size = 50

# User settings
        username map =  /etc/samba/smbusers
        idmap uid = 10000-20000000
        idmap gid = 10000-20000000
        idmap backend = ad
;       template primary group = <ad group>
        template shell = /sbin/nologin

# Winbind Settings
        winbind separator = +
        winbind enum users = Yes
        winbind enum groups  = Yes
        winbind netsted groups = Yes
        winbind nested groups = Yes
        winbind cache time = 10
        winbind use default domain = Yes

#Other Globals
        unix charset = LOCALE
        server string = <SERVERNAME>
        load printers = no
        printing =  cups
        cups options = raw

;       printcap name = /etc/printcap
        #obtain list of printers automatically on SystemV
;       printcap name = lpstat
;       printing = cups
```

squid.conf

```
auth_param ntlm program /usr/bin/ntlm_auth --require-membership-of=<DOMAINNAME>\\INTERNETZ --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp
auth_param ntlm children 10
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/squid_ldap_auth -R -b "dc=<dcname>,dc=local" -D "cn=administrator,cn=Users,dc=<domainname>,dc=local" -w "******" -f sAMAccountName=%s -h 192.168.15.19:3268
auth_param basic realm "Proxy Authentifizierung. Bitte geben Sie Ihren Benutzername und Ihr Passwort ein!" #means insert you PW in an other language - #
external_acl_type InetGroup %LOGIN /usr/lib/squid3/squid_ldap_group -R -b "dc=<domainname>,dc=local" -D "cn=administrator,cn=Users,dc=<domainname>,dc=local" -w "******" -f "(&(objectclass=person)(sAMAccountName=%v) (memberof=cn=%a,cn=internetz,dc=<domainname>,dc=local))" -h 192.168.15.19:3268

auth_param negotiate program /usr/lib/squid3/squid_kerb_auth -d
auth_param negotiate children 10
auth_param negotiate keep_alive on

acl localnet proxy_auth REQUIRED
acl InetAccess external InetGroup Internetz
http_access allow InetAccess
http_access deny all
acl auth proxy_auth REQUIRED

http_access allow auth
```

and a very suspicious is that by adding the proxy server to the Domain i see 2 new entries in the PC one with the original computer-name leopoldine and one with leopoldine
CNF:f8efa4c4-ff0e-4217-939d-f1523b43464d ?!?

I tried a lot, really... but i stuck on this problem...
i actually i even reinstalled all dependent programs and reconfigured them from default.

Group exists and has me in it. Firefox running on the old proxy and i use IE for testing the new one. But i'll get all the time Access-Denited

and to be honest i'm quite a beginner, so please don't be to prude. I'll interested in improving, i'll get the information we need to fix this but i started working 2 month ago and got only 1 1/2 year's training and not a single sec. in linux ;)

Comment: Don't know how to get squid talking to MSAD, but some time ago (before MSAD) I setup ident (rfc 1413) to address a similar problem - there are some issues with ident (relatively easy to forge, most MSWindows implementations report the console user rather than the socket owner) then it might be a viable solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

add the proxy user to the winbindd_priv group.